# How to structure CYPHER query to return a different results for none existent paths and none existent nodes

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

In my application I have setup roles which provide users with different levels of access to other users assets.

I have this query to return an asset `BobsPrivate` where user requesting is `Bob`

```
     MATCH (u:User {name: 'Bob' })
     MATCH (n:Asset:Album {name:'BobsPrivate'})
     WHERE (u)-[:CREATED|:FRIENDS_CAN_READ]->(n) OR (n)<-[:CAN_READ]-()<-[:BELONGS_TO]-(u)
     RETURN n
```

All my queries are over the REST API from node.

This works as expected and returns the asset because one of the relationships are present and if I pass a non existent asset name such as foo, it works as expected and does not return anything.

When I pass user `James` and `BobsPrivate` it also returns nothing, as you would expect but I would like to return something different.

My problem is that I get the same result for a non existent asset and a non existent relationship with the latter being equivalent to not having the proper access level.

How can I structure my query such that I can return two different results so that I can handle the HTTP response differently in my controller (404, 403)? I would also need to use this same principle in my `UPDATE` and `DELETE` methods.

EDIT:

I changed my query a little and it gives me what I'm looking for but, it does introduce another `MATCH` so I'm still open to suggestions

```
    OPTIONAL MATCH (u:User {name: 'Bob' })
    OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Asset:Album {name:'BobsPrivate'})
    WHERE (u)-[:CREATED|:FRIENDS_CAN_READ]->(n) OR (n)<-[:CAN_READ]-()<-[:BELONGS_TO]-(u)
    WITH n
    OPTIONAL MATCH (l:Asset:Album {name:'BobsPrivate'})
    RETURN n AS ASSET, l IS NOT NULL AS ASSET_EXISTS, CASE WHEN n IS NOT NULL AND l IS NOT NULL THEN true ELSE
```

What this lets me do is return the `Asset` as is, without any additional drilling down based on relationship so I can return a helpful boolean that my controller can use.

I'm new to NEO4J and I'm pretty sure there will be a better way than this so if you do know, then I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My 5-minute attempt to achieve desired behaviour:

```
MATCH (u:User {name: 'Bob' })
MATCH (n:Asset:Album {name:'BobsPrivate'})
RETURN 
  n, 
  EXISTS((u)-[:CREATED|:FRIENDS_CAN_READ]->(n)) as isDirectAccessible,
  EXISTS((n)<-[:CAN_READ]-()<-[:BELONGS_TO]-(u)) as isIndirectAccessible
```

We are retrieving all facts separately:

- Asset
- Return boolean flag, whether asset can be directly accessed
- Return boolean flag, whether asset can be indirectly accessed

Then, at a client side, we can decide what we are going to do with that. For example:

- If no data are returned at all: return 404
- If there is such asset in database, but one (or both of them) flag is false: return 403
- If asset exists, both flags are true: return 200 and data

Delete query example:

```
MATCH (u:User {name: 'Bob' })
MATCH (n:Asset:Album {name:'BobsPrivate'})
WITH 
  n, 
  EXISTS((u)-[:CREATED|:FRIENDS_CAN_READ]->(n)) as isDirectAccessible,
  EXISTS((n)<-[:CAN_READ]-()<-[:BELONGS_TO]-(u)) as isIndirectAccessible
WITH n, isDirectAccessible, isIndirectAccessible, 
  (CASE
    WHEN isDirectAccessible OR isIndirectAccessible THEN n
    ELSE null
    END) as deletableObject
DETACH DELETE deletableObject
RETURN (deletableObject IS NOT NULL) as isDeleted, isDirectAccessible, isIndirectAccessible
```

Same principles are working here:

- If nothing return, then asset do not exists
- If something return: check flags

---

Note: I am feeling that this might not be the best approach. But, hey, it works.

Comment: This is very elegant, I like it. However, I also need to use this for my delete method and as this is not checking for relationships on 'n', DELETE would just delete it regardless. Is there anyway I can use a similar approach for DELETE?

Comment: Incredible, very nice. I can use the same logic for this in my update query too thanks a lot.

Comment: @jameslouiz Please, mark my answer as correct, if this works for you :)

Comment: Of course, I'm just running it through my tests and making amends. The simple return query works perfectly :)

Comment: Don't suppose you can think of a solution for using this with SET? After the CASE there can either be a node or null and at times when this is null, SET throws an exception as it can only accept a node or a relationship. Is there a way to get around this?